# In how many words the letter of word RAINBOW be arranged so that only 2 vowels always remain together?

Tags: permutations

My Approach:

RAINBOW has 4 Consonants and 3 vowels.

Out of 3Vowels 2 vowel are selected  and  arranged in 3P2 ways

and the rest letters are arranged in 5! ways(1vowel and 2 consonants)

The Required arrangement is: 3P2*5!=720

But the Ans is 2880

Second Approach:

Out of 7 possible ways subract the one having either all vowel together or no vowel are together.

7!-(5!*3!+4!*5P3!)=2880  // i got the answer through this approach

What i have done wrong in ist approach and why the approach was wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vowel and $C$ be a consonant.

In any word (for example: V V C C C V C) there are $4!$ possibilities to rotate $C$'s, and $3!$ possibilities to rotate $V$'s. This yields $3! \cdot 4! = 144$ possibilities to rotate $C$'s and $V$'s in a word.

When two $V$'s are in the first and second place, there are $4$ ways to put the third $V$ (same goes when two $V$'s are at the end). When two $V$'s are in the middle, there are $3$ ways to put the third $V$. You have 4 situations when two $V$'s are in the middle. So the number of permitted settings is $4 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 4 = 20$.

Now the total number of possiblities is $20 \cdot 144 = 2880$.

Comment: Can you think of a shorter approach?

Comment: Not really, but I would like to see a simpler one.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal i think second approach would work fine with you

Comment: @WojciechKarwacki I think the second approach would be simpler

Comment: @WojciechKarwacki: See if you like my answer

Answer (score 2):

*Simple "gap" method*

$- C - C - C - C -$

Position blocks of 2 and 1 vowel in two gaps and permute in $_5P_2\cdot 3!$ = 120 ways

Permute consonants in their places to give 120*4! = 2880

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you fix the position of the vowels as if, for example, they're always the first and second letters of the word. So you have to multiply 720 for 6 and then subtract two times the words in which all vowels are together

Comment: why to multiple by 6?

Comment: You can see the block of two vowels you choose as a single letter, so you have $6!$. You wrote $5!$ so you had to multiply by 6

Answer (score 0):

[image] This is the solution $($page $2)$

Answer (score -2):

[image] This is the solution $($page $1)$

Comment: Please type your solution. Don't just give a link.